# Stepping Into Third Party Source Code

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have the C# source code for a third party control that I am using in my vb.net project.  I set the third party source code as a project reference in my actual project.  I am trying to step into the third party source code through my project and it's not working - the debugger keeps continuing on in my project code, and doesn't step into the third party method.  I unchecked 'Just my Code' in the debugging options, and am not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: Do you have a debug build and a .pdb file of the project? If you have the source code it might be simpler to rebuild it yourself.

Comment: I have the source code.  I rebuilt the source code, the .pdb file isn't in my project's debug folder.

Comment: If you have sources of third party project, then build it in debug mode, and reference compiled assembly by your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Reflector Pro](http://www.reflector.net/) (trial available) for debugging third party assemblies. It allows dynamic decompilation inside Visual Studio and setting breakpoints on decompiled sources.

Comment: +1 Indeed, it's very good.  It's also a good way to end the battle with .net source code stepping.